# Cannot Find ProjectName.resources File at Runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a Windows Form application, with several forms. A new error emerged recently, despite no code changes I am aware of. At runtime, when a specific form is created, it fails with an error, stating it cannot find a file. The filename is *ProjectName*.resources.

The form in question does have some images. I assumed I may have deleted on of them, resulting in it no longer being compiled as a resource at build time. Pointing them to valid image paths does not fix the problem, however.

Using ILSpy, I see a resource file for every form (with resources), of the form *ProjectName.FormName*.resources. However, there is not a *ProjectName*.resources file.

This only happens with one of the forms.

How do I fix this resolution error?

Comment: Check if you have proper action set on this for `.resources` file (solution explorer -> click on file -> properties -> build action -> embedded resource)

Comment: The build action for Resources.resx is embedded resource.

Comment: So it worked before you deleted image? Can you check in your source control (hope you use one), what changes you made to projects (`.csproj`) files?

Comment: No source control on this particular project. I'd be fine remaking the form, more or less, if it would fix it, I just don't know what the exact problem is.

Comment: And what happens when you add a resources file to the project?

Comment: Coming to think of it, there may be a resource file already since you said it was working: check if there are any orphan `.resx` files that aren't in the project - you might have removed it by accident.

Comment: Is there a way I can regenerate all required resource files? I tried deleting what I had and remaking it, but this problems recurs even on new forms (old ones still work though, except the specific one).